# Do Mystic abilities count as spells for Rage-purposes?

Tags: dnd-5e, psionics, barbarian, unearthed-arcana, rage

If the mystic abilities are explicitly said to not be spells can you RAW use them while raging?

> **Mystics**: Psionics is a special form of magic use, distinct from spellcasting.
>
> **Barbarian**: If you are able to cast Spells, you can't cast them or concentrate on them while raging.

Latest version of mystic:
https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given this passage on **page 9** under **Duration: Concentration** first sentence of the second paragraph.

> Concentrating on  a   discipline  follows the same    rules   as  concentrating   on  a   spell.

I would rule, that you cannot concentrate on a discipline while raging.

But aside from that, **disciplines are strictly no spells**, so RAW you are able to use them while in rage. (Unless the Discipline says 'you cast *some* spell'.)

#### Rules as Intended:

[Mike Mearls mentioned in a tweet, that it shouldn't be possible:](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/619584829030412288)

> **@Spiritmaster111:** @mikemearls Also, can a Mystic/Barbarian multiclass use disciplines while raging? Rage only mentions casting and concentrating on spells.
>
> **@mikemearls:** @Spiritmaster111 should also apply to psionics - thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Note that RAW interpretations are kind of pointless at this point in time (_2017-07_) because the material is still in Beta. Right now it's all kind of _"rules as proposed"_ :)